# Check and circle marks in test papers

Tags: culture

While watching anime, especially ones that focus on slice-of-life or high school, I often come across a test paper containing a character's score. However, it is interesting to note that the correct answers are **circled** while the wrong ones are **ticked** (checked?). As far as I know, ticks are for correct answers and circles are for incorrect answers (unless I've been living in a shell, which would be embarrassing).

[image: Four Girls and an Idol]

The image is from The World God Only Knows OVA: Four Girls and an Idol, where Keima Katsuragi intentionally placed an incorrect answer for question #1. As you can see, it is checked while the rest are circled. Does this mirror how Japan marks the test papers of students? If so, why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this does mirror how Japan marks the test papers of students. Let's see an example each of a marked test paper in anime and in real life Japan:

[image: Yui Hirasawa's abysmal math test score]

[image: Sample of a graded arithmetic drill]

[Circles and crosses](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%80%87%C3%97) indicate right and wrong answers, but you'll often see check marks used in place of crosses to save time and effort. Check marks are sometimes called *reten* for bearing resemblance to the katakana *re*, but should not be confused with the return marker *[reten](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%AC%E7%82%B9)* that [annotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun) Classical Chinese. Check marks call forth the attention of students to incorrect answers, which they should ***check*** again.

The check mark as an error mark also sees usage in countries like Korea and Sweden, but as you can gather from the discussions on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/1f3ron/why_is_o_yes_an_x_no_in_japanese_playstation/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Check_mark#Ticks_in_various_cultures_.2F_Yes_vs._No), there really is no *universal* standard for marking right and wrong answers even within a country. The graders may choose whatever the mark they want. My teachers in school thought that ticking off wrong answers wastes too much ink, so they just cheaply impressed a dot by the wrong answers.

Occasionally, you might also encounter the [flower circle](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%8A%B1%E4%B8%B8), [double circle](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%8C%E9%87%8D%E4%B8%B8) and [triangle](http://jisho.org/word/%E2%96%B3) marks, which denote, respectively, perfect, good and average (poor) work done by the students.

[image: Hanamaru]